# Backend - жизненный цикл пользователя

Tags: backend

Есть сервер и база данных, сервер умеет регистрировать пользователей, держать сесии, база данных - хранит данные о пользователях и так далее.. Нужно научить сервер удалять неактивных пользователей, как подобное делать? Можно сделать таймер убийцу, но вот как оно работает с большими сегментами данных? Что если нужно обработать и удалить несколько миллиардов таблиц, интересует как подобное работает в больших системах

Comment: Каждый день запускается фоновая задача, которая выполняет что-нибудь вроде `delete from users where last_login < now() - interval '1 year';`

Comment: *"..обработать и удалить несколько **миллиардов** таблиц.."* - не опечатка?